# Login Failed - LocalDB, EF, WebSecurity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, localdb

I have a domain-model and a webGUI in form of a MVC-project, I havent migrated any of the DB-content when changes has been made to the domain-model, instead i have just changed the "Initial Catalog" in the connectionstring to a new name and the localDB has just created a new(Maybe a dumb way to do it but it has worked)

Now i have added Websecurity, it worked like a charm the first time, but when i change the name on "initial catalog" i get a;

**"Cannot open database "Dev1" requested by the login. The login Failed"**

**"Login Failed for user 'My-Comuter\MyUser"**

on this line in  Application_Start();

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("EFDbContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
```

If I the changes to the domain-model and change back the name on the "Inital Catalog" it works.

My connectionstring looks like this;

```
<add name="EFDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localDB)\v11.0; Initial Catalog = Dev1;Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Trusted_Connection=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

and the context class like this;

```
using MyApp.Domain.Entities;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MyApp.Domain.Concrete
{
    public class EFDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<SomeData> SomeDataSet{ get; set; }    
        public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfiles { get; set; }

    }       
}
```

**If i havent added enought information or code, just say the word and i will try to provide it**

Is there anything wrong in the connectionstring or EFDContext implementation? Any input would be appriciated:)

Comment: Can you confirm that the login your app is trying to use can actually log in and has the appropriate permissions to access the Dev1 database?

Comment: Yes, when i use the first "db" i can create/login and so on.

Comment: And if i comment out Websecurity it also works. Im so curious to where i have messed up. :)

Comment: Check the UserProfile table.  Is it UserProfiles (plural)?  If so, update the line in Application_Start.

Comment: The table is Userprofile, the DbSet is plural. Userprofiles. Would it help if you got to see more code?

Comment: Are you able to connect to the Dev1 database if you use SQL Server and your Windows Credentials?

Comment: I dont have SQL-server MS installed, But i cant find Dev1 anywhere, the previous i can find. Dev1 should be created on the fly using code first (right?)... If i comment the Websecurity line out. Dev1 is created. Thanks for the reply, i feel im stuck in my own line of thought.

Comment: It should be created automatically with code first.  If you go to the server explorer in Visual Studio and click on the Data Connections do you see the EFDbContext with your tables in it?

Comment: If i use the "new" name i see it under "DefaultConnection" but i cant connect to it "Cannot open database "Dev1" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'Computer\Name'. But if i connect to the old folder i can browse it.

Comment: In the Application_Start() method and connectionString try changing EFDbContext to "DefaultConnection."  If it doesn't work change it back.  Are you using MVC3 or MVC4?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38048/discussion-between-andrew-and-tim)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke with him in the chat and found out what he needs to update.  Hopefully this will help others:

1. In the Server Explorer, under Data Connections make sure the connection is EFDbContext
2. In your Application_Start() Method add the following if statement around the WebSecurity line to prevent the initialization happening more than once:

   ```
   System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseAlways<EFDbContext>());
   // System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(EFDbContext>(null);

   if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("EFDbContext", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
   ```
3. Change the initial catalog in the connection string to the database name

Comment: I finally got it to work, but now its a two-stage rocket. I firstly create the DB without using websecurity, after that i enable it and run the app again. Could i create the WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection at some other place when i know the tables are up?

Comment: I updated my answer.  Before you had DropCreateDatabaseIfModelchanges, but since it was the first time running the program there wasn't any models so that line wasn't being called and the tables were not being created.  If we change it to DropCreateDatabaseAlways, it should create the tables and then the WebSecurity.Initialze... should work.  Make sure you comment the DropCreateDatabaseAlways line and uncomment the line below or you will drop your database every time you run the program.

Comment: I tried the code above but i still got the same login-error. Im i maybe stuck to the "two step" soulotion?